# what happens when a CUDA kernel is called?

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm wondering what happens in a CUDA program when a line like

```
myKernel<<<16,4>>>(arg1,arg2);
```

is encountered.

What happens then? Is the CUDA driver invoked and the ptx code passed to it or what?

Comment: Did you have a look at the assembly output of your compiler?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"It just works".  Just kidding.  Probably I will get flamed for posting this answer, as my knowledge is not extensive in this area.  But this is what I can say:

- The nvcc code processor is a compiler driver, meaning it uses multiple compilers and steers pieces of code in one direction or another.  You might want to read more about the nvcc toolchain [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#cuda-compilation-trajectory) if you have questions like these.  Anyway, *one* of the things the nvcc tool will do is replace the kernel launch syntax `mykernel<<<...>>>` with a sequence of api calls (served by various cuda and GPU api libraries).  This is how the cuda driver gets "invoked" under the hood.
- As part of this invocation sequence, the driver will perform a variety of tasks.  It will inspect the executable to see if it contains appropriate SASS (device assembly) code.  The device does not actually execute [PTX](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html), which is an intermediate code, but SASS.  If no appropriate SASS is available, but PTX code is available in the image, the driver will do a [JIT-compile](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#just-in-time-compilation) step to create the SASS. (In fact, some of this actually happens at context creation time/CUDA lazy initialization, rather than at the point of the kernel launch.)
- Additionally, in the invocation sequence, the driver will do various types of device status checking, data validity checking (e.g. kernel launch configuration parameters), and data copying (e.g. kernel sass code, kernel parameters) to the device.
- Finally, the driver will initiate execution on the device, and then immediately return control to the host thread.

Additional insight into kernel execution may be obtained by studying [kernel execution in the driver API](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#kernel-execution).  To briefly describe the driver API, I could call it a "lower level" API than the cuda runtime API.  However, the point of mentioning it is that it may give some insight into how a kernel launch syntax (runtime API) could be translated into a C-level API that actually looks like library calls.

Someone else may come along with a better/more detailed explanation.